# Add constraint on combination of multiple fields of prisma model

Tags: prisma

I have this model in Prisma:

```
model RegisteredPage {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  domain String // instagram, youtube,...
  page   String // s4eed, dive, makeappwithme,...
}
```

I want to add a constraint on the `domain` and `page` so that combination of them is unique. Should I make the combination of them as `ID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `@@unique` attribute.

Unique attributes can be defined on multiple fields using the `@@unique`  attribute, (also called composite or compound unique constraints).

This would define a composite unique index on combination of domain and page fields.

```
model RegisteredPage {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  domain String // instagram, youtube,...
  page   String // s4eed, dive, makeappwithme,...

  @@unique([domain, page])
}
```

Here's a Reference for using the [@@unique](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-a-unique-field) attribute.